# Nginx vs Apache proxy pass

Tags: nginx

I am trying to convert my apache config to nginx. For apache I have following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName loc.goout.net
    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
        ProxyPreserveHost On
    </Location>
    <Location /i/>
        ProxyPass https://dev.goout.net/i/ retry=0
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
    </Location>
    ...
```

Like this, if I fetch:

https://loc.goout.net/i/user/606456_001_min.jpg

It correctly fetches content from:

https://dev.goout.net/i/user/606456_001_min.jpg

So for nginx I am trying this:

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             loc.goout.net;

    proxy_buffering         off;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host            dev.goout.net;

    location /i/ {
        proxy_pass          https://dev.goout.net:443;
    }
```

But when I fetch the content, I will always get `502`.

In nginx logs I see following:

```
[error] 7#7: *5 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: loc.goout.net, request: "GET /i/user/606456_001_min.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://dev.goout.net/i/user/606456_001_min.jpg", host: "loc.goout.net"
```

Note the link: https://dev.goout.net/i/user/606456_001_min.jpg 
- which works correctly. It seems to me it still doesn't connect with SSL. I also tried to define the upstream section as:

```
upstream backend {
    server dev.goout.net:443;
}
```

But it had no effect.

Note the server is behind CloudFlare gateway, I hope it is not preventing the correct connection, but I guess that wouldn't work in apache either.

Comment: Few things you can do. Try with `https://dev.goout.net;` without the `:443` and see if it works. Als you may want to add `proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;`. Let me know if those doesn't help

Comment: I already tried both things :/

Comment: Can you telnet `dev.goout.net 443` from the nginx server machine?

Comment: @Vojtěch, can you make sure to accept and/or award the bounty?  otherwise, the whole bounty would be lost.  I trust my answer solves the issue 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***tl;dr: SNI is off by default in nginx, as per http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ssl_server_name, but is required by Cloudflare.***

---

It's generally not the best idea to have home-made proxies on top of Cloudflare — it's supposed to be the other way around.

However, what you're omitting is the actual error message that results from making the request like `curl -v localhost:3227/i/user/606456_001_min.jpg` — of course it is TLS-related:

`2018/07/07 23:18:39 [error] 33345#33345: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: loc.goout.net, request: "GET /i/user/606456_001_min.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:7303]:443/i/user/606456_001_min.jpg", host: "localhost:3227"`

This is because nginx is not really intended to be used to steal someone else's sites via `proxy_pass`, so, some features that Cloudflare does require, are turned off by default in nginx for the general use; specifically, it's the [***SNI, Server Name Indication*** extension to TLS](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), that's making the difference here.

As per http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ssl_server_name, putting an extra **`proxy_ssl_server_name on;`** to your exact configuration does fix the issue (I've tested this myself — it works) — note that this requires nginx 1.7.0 or newer.

```
+   proxy_ssl_server_name   on;     # SNI is off by default
```

---

Additionally, note that you'll also have to ensure that the domain name resolution gets updated during the run-time, as, by default, it only gets resolved when the configuration is loaded or reloaded; you could use the [trick](//stackoverflow.com/a/33325584/1122270) of using variables within your http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass to make it update the resolution of the host as appropriate, but then this also requires you to use the http://nginx.org/r/resolver directive to specify the server to use for DNS resolutions (during the runtime, after loading the configuration), so, your MVP would then be:

```
location /i/ {
    resolver                1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com.;
    proxy_ssl_server_name   on;     # SNI is off by default
    proxy_pass              https://dev.goout.net:443$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I would never find this out.

Comment: @Vojtěch, I didn't use Google myself, as the documentation of nginx is easier to read than Google, but trying to find duplicates of this now, it's actually pretty easy if you simply Google the actual error message from http://nginx.org/r/error_log — the one I included in my answer.  Was it somehow missing in your error.log?  It's present in both `nginx/1.2.1` and `nginx/1.12.1` for me on a `Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to specify upstream servers by hostname instead of IP then you must define a `resolver` directive for Nginx to do DNS look ups.

Is dev.goout.net on a different, remote machine?

Where are your `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` directives? That connection won't just secure itself.

Comment: 1. I guess I don't need `resolver` directive as it works correctly for non-https. 2. `dev.goout.net` is on different, public machine. 3. These are necessary for self-signed certificate, this one is trusted cert.